# Scifi comic from the 90s about an organic spaceship and its captain in an incubator

Tags: story-identification, comics

Back in the 90s I read a comic book about a group of bounty hunters (not sure anymore) in space, who killed a gigantic space lifeform (somewhing like a whale in free space) by going into its guts and blowing up a bomb there. Their captain was seriously injured by the stomach acid of the lifeform.

After they killed the lifeform, they used the exoskeleton of the dead lifeform as their new spaceship.

Their captain from now on due to his burnings was forced to live inside some kind of incubator inside the ship and controling it by some kind of telepathy.

Comment: Sounds like some grimdark sci-fi, could it have been in Heavy Metal?

Comment: @Boelabaal: I watched the movio heavy metal fakk2, it wasn't something like that. I remember the comic being rather serious and dark and there wasn't any notable humour nor erotic scenes.

Comment: Do you recall if it was a European, American or Japanese comic? Was it in colour?

Comment: It was in color. It wasn't manga/anime style. Style was rather realistic, not exaggerated as american/superhero comics often are.

Answer (score 11):

Not an exact match but I think it could be Alejandro Jodorowsky's The Metabarons.

In [***Book 3:Aghnar***](https://www.humanoids.com/y_catalog/book/id/444) Othon flies into the mouth of a whale/cyborg/ship called a Cetacyborg  and is able to destroy it from the inside. However, the Cetacyborg’s intestinal acid corrodes Othon’s lungs in the process.
[image]

[image]

[image]

At a later point his son is able to take command of another Cetacyborg by mind controlling it's pilots.

Comment: This comes close somehow but it was different in my memory. I remember men with spacesuits walking inside the testines of the organic ship and carrying the bomb with them to kill the lifeform from the inside.